# How to fix padding on body

Tags: css

I got this white padding on my homepage https://cyclingland.github.io/home.html
and I can't find the issue in my css... If someone can find the issue you're a hero!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `margin-left: 20px` from `#intro`.

This is creating the extra white space on the left side of your website.

You also need an additional change. Not sure if intended because your `height: 100%` on `#intro` is being overridden.

So basically your CSS class in `cyclingland.css` should look like -

```
.intro {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100% !important;
    /* margin-left: 20px; */
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: it's better to write your answer as a comment for such simple questions like that.

Comment: You want me to reply the post and the code as a comment O_o? It's not just 1 quick fix, it also has a suggestion going with it which might need attention? Before being a police, please check sir. :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I completely overlooked that!

Answer (score 0):

You're not being specific here, but if it's the left white "padding" on the main content the `#intro` has a `margin-left: 20px` property set.